# Web scraping data and using loop to update the dataframe data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am trying to create a dataframe which can update data on the first row. Firstly, I create this dataframe and it works. the code looks like this:

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

```
for i in range(100):

    def priceTracker():
       url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAL'

       response = requests.get(url)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
       price = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'})[0].find('span').text
       return price

    record = []
    record.append({'Ticker': 'AAL', 'Price':priceTracker()})
    df = pd.DataFrame(record)
    df.set_index(['Ticker'],inplace=True)
    print(df)
```

And then, I try to use loop function to run this code in order to get the price column update automatically. It works, however, the output unable to show on the same row.

Comment: why do you use jupyter for this? Why not run it normaly `python script.py`? Maybe first use `print()` to see what you get in variables. maybe server doesn't send new values because there is  no new values? OR maybe server blocks bots/scripts/hackers/spamers nd it sends you warning with Captcha. You should first chekc what you get in `response.text`.

Comment: if you need to run it loop then use loop - ie. `while True:` - but at this moment I don't see any loop in your code.

Comment: it seems you use it in jupyter but normally you have to use `print(df)` to see data in dataframe.

Comment: do you know modue [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance)? It may be better then manually get data from web page.